# What is the proper way to use the node.js postgresql module?

Tags: javascript, postgresql, node.js, heroku

I am writing a node.js app on Heroku and using the [pg module](https://github.com/brianc/node-postgres). I can't figure out the "right" way to get a client object for each request that I need to query the database.

The documentation uses code like this:

```
pg.connect(conString, function(err, client) {
  // Use the client to do things here
});
```

But surely you don't need to call `pg.connect` inside every function that uses the database right? I've seen [other code](https://github.com/metadaddy-sfdc/node_chat) that does this:

```
var conString = process.env.DATABASE_URL || "tcp://postgres:1234@localhost/postgres";
var client = new pg.Client(conString);
client.connect();
// client is a global so you can use it anywhere now
```

I am leaning toward the second option since I believe the free database instance for Heroku is limited to one connection anyway, but are there any drawbacks to doing it this way? Do I need to check if my client object is still connected every time before I use it?

Answer (score 167, accepted):

I'm the author of [node-postgres](https://github.com/brianc/node-postgres). First, I apologize the documentation has failed to make the right option clear: that's my fault.  I'll try to improve it. I wrote [a Gist](https://gist.github.com/brianc/6908287) just now to explain this because [the conversation](https://gist.github.com/brianc/6908287) grew too long for Twitter.

> Using `pg.connect` is **the way to go** in a web environment.
>
> PostgreSQL server can only handle 1 query at a time per connection. 
>   That means if you have 1 global `new pg.Client()` connected to your
>   backend your entire app is bottleknecked based on how fast postgres
>   can respond to queries.  It literally will line everything up, queuing
>   each query.  Yeah, it's async and so that's alright...but wouldn't you
>   rather multiply your throughput by 10x?  Use `pg.connect`  set the
>   `pg.defaults.poolSize` to something sane (we do 25-100, not sure the
>   right number yet).
>
> `new pg.Client` is for when you know what you're doing.  When you need
>   a single long lived client for some reason or need to very carefully
>   control the life-cycle.  A good example of this is when using
>   `LISTEN/NOTIFY`.  The listening client needs to be around and
>   connected and not shared so it can properly handle `NOTIFY` messages. 
>   Other example would be when opening up a 1-off client to kill some
>   hung stuff or in command line scripts.

One very helpful thing is to centralize all access to your database in your app to one file.  Don't litter `pg.connect` calls or new clients throughout. Have a file like `db.js` that looks something like this:

```
module.exports = {
   query: function(text, values, cb) {
      pg.connect(function(err, client, done) {
        client.query(text, values, function(err, result) {
          done();
          cb(err, result);
        })
      });
   }
}
```

This way you can change out your implementation from `pg.connect` to a custom pool of clients or whatever and only have to change things in one place.

Have a look at the [node-pg-query module](https://github.com/brianc/node-pg-query) that does just this.

Comment: Sorry, I'm fairly new to DBMS and I still have a problem understanding this, but why don't we want to "litter pg.connect" calls? Is it for simplicity or due to performance reason? For example, I call pg.connect once in each of the routes I have in my basic app (all with the same conString). Is this okay? Intuitively, it feels like it's making a new connection to the same db whenever I call it (which I don't want), but does it use the pooled connections internally? Thanks.

Comment: Awesome. Why are you employing one connection per query instead of one per request? I've been looking for an appropriate way to share a connection across multiple queries within a request and had been considering res.locals prior to finding your answer here.

Comment: Oh wait. It looks like your solution here won't support transactions.

Comment: This should be permalinked to the github.

Comment: @brianc I'm also new to RDBMS. As reading pg's documentation seems like Client Pooling is the way to go for big websites (or not?). `pg-query` uses client pooling? If not, do you have an example how to write a `db.js` when you put your request inside `pool.connect((err, client, done) => {});`? The `max number of clients in the pool` can be very high number, like 10000? And what does it mean exactly? At the exact same moment the database can't handle more visitors than this number?

Comment: Do I have to call client.end() at the end of the callback?

Comment: awesome library but this confuses me as well. Perhaps a code example with setInterval(console.log... ) with pooling and without to show exactly what's going on.

Comment: What if i have to call cb back in case of error in pg.connect. Something like this
`module.exports = {
   query: function(text, values, cb) {
      pg.connect(function(err, client, done) {
      if (err)
      {
           cb(null, values);     
      }
        client.query(text, values, function(err, result) {
          done();
          cb(err, result);
        })
      });
   }
}`

by calling cb(null, values) from error block, sockets are increased in unix server. I am checking sockets by this command **ls -ltr /proc/cat /path of pid/fd/ | grep socket | wc -l**

Comment: How to close pg connection?

Comment: Note that pg.connect was removed post v7 of node-postgres aka pg. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45174120/pg-connect-not-a-function

Answer (score 26):

I am the author of [pg-promise](https://github.com/vitaly-t/pg-promise), which simplifies the use of [node-postgres](https://github.com/brianc/node-postgres) via promises.

It addresses the issues about the right way of connecting to and disconnecting from the database, using the connection pool implemented by [node-postgres](https://github.com/brianc/node-postgres), among other things, like automated transactions.

An individual request in [pg-promise](https://github.com/vitaly-t/pg-promise) boils down to just what's relevant to your business logic:

```
db.any('SELECT * FROM users WHERE status = $1', ['active'])
    .then(data => {
        console.log('DATA:', data);
    })
    .catch(error => {
        console.log('ERROR:', error);
    });
```

i.e. you do not need to deal with connection logic when executing queries, because you set up the connection only once, globally, like this:

```
const pgp = require('pg-promise')(/*options*/);

const cn = {
    host: 'localhost', // server name or IP address;
    port: 5432,
    database: 'myDatabase',
    user: 'myUser',
    password: 'myPassword'
};
// alternative:
// const cn = 'postgres://username:password@host:port/database';

const db = pgp(cn); // database instance;
```

You can find many more examples in [Learn by Example](https://github.com/vitaly-t/pg-promise/wiki/Learn-by-Example) tutorial, or on the [project's home page](https://github.com/vitaly-t/pg-promise).

Comment: Hi, Heroku only accepts SSL connections. In `pg` this is specified by `pg.defaults.ssl = true;`. How do you do this in `pg-promise`?

Comment: @ocram https://github.com/vitaly-t/pg-promise/wiki/FAQ#how-to-access-the-instance-of-node-postgres-thats-used, or you can specify SSL within the connection parameters: https://github.com/vitaly-t/pg-promise/wiki/Connection-Syntax

Comment: I'm new to most of this: javascript, promises, postgres, etc. and this is exactly what I needed. Thank you!!

Comment: @ocram I just got this working by doing `pgp.pg.defaults.ssl = true;`

Comment: will this create multiple connections to improve the postgres throughput automatically when we give multiple query request to postgres?

Comment: @sundar Yes, it will. It has each [Database](http://vitaly-t.github.io/pg-promise/Database.html) object contain property [$pool](http://vitaly-t.github.io/pg-promise/Database.html#$pool) set to the dynamic connections pool, same as you would use with the low-level driver ;)

Answer (score 10):

Pool is the way to go now.Some thing like this

```
const { Pool } = require('pg');

    const pool = new Pool({
      connectionString: DATABASE_URL,
      ssl: false,
      max: 20,
      idleTimeoutMillis: 30000,
      connectionTimeoutMillis: 2000,
    });
    module.exports = {
        query: (text, params) => pool.query(text, params)
      }
```

it can be used as `db.query('<BEGIN,COMMIT,ROLLBACK,your query,anything')`

Answer (score 1):

It is better to create a pg pool globally and each time you need to do a db operation use the client and then release it back to the pool. Once all db operations are done end the pool using `pool.end()`

Sample code -

```
let pool = new pg.Pool(dbConfig);
pool.connect(function(err, client, done) {

if (err) {
    console.error('Error connecting to pg server' + err.stack);
    callback(err);
} else {
    console.log('Connection established with pg db server');

    client.query("select * from employee", (err, res) => {

            if (err) {
                console.error('Error executing query on pg db' + err.stack);
                callback(err);
            } else {
                console.log('Got query results : ' + res.rows.length);


               async.each(res.rows, function(empRecord) {   
                        console.log(empRecord.name);
                });
            }
            client.release();

        });
}

});
```

For more details, you can refer to my blog post -[Source](http://opensourceforgeeks.blogspot.in/2017/11/how-to-connect-to-postgres-rds-from.html)

Answer (score 0):

As you can see from the [documentation](https://github.com/brianc/node-postgres) both options are valid, so choose whichever you prefer. As you, I would go with the second choice.

Comment: What about reconnecting when the connection drops? Is that done automatically? The wiki page on error handling is... empty https://github.com/brianc/node-postgres/wiki/Error-handling

Comment: I've asked it separately: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15619456/how-do-i-use-node-postgres-in-a-server

Answer (score -2):

Here's how I do it, sort of an "all of the above approach"

```
Promise = require 'bluebird'
pg = module.exports = require 'pg'

Promise.promisifyAll pg.Client.prototype
Promise.promisifyAll pg.Client
Promise.promisifyAll pg.Connection.prototype
Promise.promisifyAll pg.Connection
Promise.promisifyAll pg.Query.prototype
Promise.promisifyAll pg.Query
Promise.promisifyAll pg

connectionString = process.env.DATABASE_URL

module.exports.queryAsync = (sql, values) ->
  pg.connectAsync connectionString
  .spread (connection, release) ->
    connection.queryAsync sql, values
    .then (result) ->
      console.log result.rows[0]
    .finally ->
      release()
```

Comment: So you will end up with no connection management, no transactions support and no tasks support. What's the point then?

Comment: what language is that? coffee? berk