# Mocha/Node.js/PostgreSQL integration testing

Tags: javascript, node.js, postgresql

I have been trying to get this to work for days. I've looked around the internets and on StackOverflow. There are examples of how to test APIs using MongoDB and how to write Mocha tests that execute PSQL commands. That's not what I want.

I created a wrapper for [pg](https://github.com/brianc/node-postgres), called `db.js` from the instructions [in this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8484404/what-is-the-proper-way-to-use-the-node-js-postgresql-module) (note my comments in the calls to `console.log()`:

```
pg = require("pg");
config = require("./../config.js");

module.exports = { 
    query: function(text, values, cb) {
        console.log("I get to this in Mocha");
        pg.connect(config.connectionString, function(err, client, done) {
            console.log("I never get here");
            if (err) return console.error("error connecting to postgres: ", err);
            client.query(text, values, function(err, result) {
                console.log("I most certainly never get here");
                done();
                cb(err, result);
            })
        });
    }
}
```

With that, I can do the following:

```
$ node
$ var db = require ("./path/to/db.js");
$ db.query("insert into sometable(id, value) values(1, \"blah\")", {}, function (err, result) {
            if (err) { console.error ("db errored out man"); }
            console.log("no error...");
            console.log(result);
        });
```

Believe it or not, *that* works without a hitch!

What I can't do is the same thing in a `mocha` test (i.e., `db.spec.js`):

```
var db = require("./../../../Data/db.js");

// These tests assume you have run the scripts in the -SQL repo
describe("module: db", function() {
    it("provides a wrapper for the execution of queries", function () {
        db.query("insert into employer.profile \
            (id, returncustomer, receiveupdates, name, email, password, active) \
            values (4, true, true, 'someNameLol', 'ce@spam.org', 'change_me', true)", {}, 
            function (err, stdout, stderr) { 
                console.log(err || ""); 
                console.log(stdout || ""); 
                console.log(stderr || ""); 
            }
        );
    });
});
```

Help! I want to be able to write integration tests using my database connection. Are there components I'm missing? Required libraries?

This is all hand-rolled, I'm not using an IDE, because I want to understand how it's supposed to work by myself.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to include the `done` parameter, and call it at the end of your test.

```
describe("module: db", function() {
    it("provides a wrapper for the execution of queries", function (done) {
        db.query("insert into employer.profile \
            (id, returncustomer, receiveupdates, name, email, password, active) \
            values (4, true, true, 'someNameLol', 'ce@spam.org', 'change_me', true)", {}, 
            function (err, stdout, stderr) { 
                console.log(err || ""); 
                console.log(stdout || ""); 
                console.log(stderr || ""); 
                done();
            }
        );
    });
});
```

Comment: I know I'm supposed to avoid comments like "Thanks!" But... THANK YOU.