# Auth0 Postgresql getting error - this._connectionCallback is not a function

Tags: javascript, postgresql, auth0

I am trying to connect a custom database to auth0 and am using their default Postgres script.

I can't figure out why I am getting the following error:

> this._connectionCallback is not a function

connectionCallback doesn't exist in the snippet. Here's the 'verify' snippet:

```
function verify (email, callback) {
  //this example uses the "pg" library

  const { Client } = require("pg");
  const conString = new 
  Client({connectionString:'postgresql://postgres:password@database:port/host'});

  conString.connect(conString, function (err, client, done) {
    if (err) return callback(err);

    const query = 'UPDATE auth_user SET email_Verified = true WHERE email_Verified = false AND email = $1';
    client.query(query, [email], function (err, result) {
      done();

      return callback(err, result && result.rowCount > 0);
    });
  });
}
```

Why do I get this error?

Comment: show the place in the code where you call function verify()

Comment: @WiatroBosy it's handled through Auth0. I don't have any written code for this.

Comment: you show the function verify code - this function is called somewhere - and that's where the error is

Comment: So then it seems like this is an Auth0 issue and I'll likely have to log a ticket with them. Thanks for the help!

Comment: not necessarily - you just didn't check for an error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution in this thread - [pg.connect not a function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45174120/pg-connect-not-a-function)

Basically, pg.connect has been hard-deprecated in favor of pg.Pool, as documented here: https://node-postgres.com/guides/upgrading

So the functional code now looks like this:

```
function verify (email, callback) {

  const bcrypt = require('bcrypt');
  const pg = require("pg");
  var pool = new pg.Pool({
        user: '**',
        host: '**',
        database: '**',
        password: '**',
        port: **,
  });

  pool.connect(function (err, client, done) {
    if (err) 
      console.log('error');
    { console.log(err); return callback(err); }

    const query = 'UPDATE auth_user SET email_Verified = true WHERE email_Verified = false AND email = $1';
    client.query(query, [email], function (err, result) {
      done();
console.log(err);
      return callback(err, result && result.rowCount > 0);
    });
  });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
function verify (email, callback) {
  //this example uses the "pg" library

  const { Client } = require("pg");
  const conString = new 
  Client({connectionString:'postgresql://postgres:password@database:port/host'});

  conString.connect(conString, function (err, client, done) {
    if (err) 
    { console.log(err); return callback(err); }

    const query = 'UPDATE auth_user SET email_Verified = true WHERE email_Verified = false AND email = $1';
    client.query(query, [email], function (err, result) {
      done();
console.log(err);
      return callback(err, result && result.rowCount > 0);
    });
  });
}
```

for test check this code

Comment: the logged error looks like this:
"code": 500,
"error": "Script generated an unhandled asynchronous exception.",
"details": "TypeError: this._connectionCallback is not a function",
"name": "TypeError",
"message": "this._connectionCallback is not a function",